# How to make main javafx window still resizable coming back from full screen mode in MacOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx, macos-sierra

This issue is regarding `JavaFX (jdk-9.0.1)` on `MacOS` (I run Sierra). I'm developing a x-platform desktop app with a resizable main window `primaryStage.setResizable(true)`, after I have clicked the little green button,`see picture below`, to go into full screen mode and then back again to normal mode the resizing of the window is no longer possible. How can I make it still resizable after coming back from full screen mode on MacOS?. It works on Windows and Linux but not on MacOS. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: screenshot maximize button in macos]

**Edit 1**: The issue is now reported and visible on `bugs.java.com` at the following url [JDK-8191885](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8191885)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mipa! I discovered that it is even better to add a listener to the `fullScreenProperty()`, then you don't have to click into the title bar and move it a few pixels. The key was to do `setResizable(false)` followed by `setResizable(true)` though, thank you for finding that out. I will go with this workaround until the bug is fixed:

```
    primaryStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((v,o,n) -> {

        if (!primaryStage.isFullScreen()) {

            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is not even planned to fix this bug before Java 11, we probably have to live with it for quite some time. I therefore have tried to find some kind of workarround for it and here it is:

Add this or something similar to your code.

```
primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((v,o,n) -> {
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setResizable(true);
});
```

Once you have de-maximized your stage via the green button the only thing you still have to do manually is to click into the title bar of your stage and move it for a few pixels. After that the stage should be resizable with the mouse again as usual. Its a nasty hack but still better than having to live with this bug forever.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I discovered that it was even better to add a listener to the fullScreenProperty() which is called when resuming back to normal screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in JavaFX. I can reproduce this behaviour with JDK9 and 10ea. It still seems to work though for the latest JDK8. I have not found any workarround yet. You should report this at http://bugreport.java.com/